# EF Core conversion and non nullable type converted to a nullable primitive

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, non-nullable

I have a class `MyClass` that has a non nullable property `Maybe<int>` `MyMproperty`.

```
#nullable enable
public class MyClass
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Maybe<int> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
#nullable restore
```

I declare and use en EF conversion in my `MyContext`:

```
builderEntity.Property(o => o.MyProperty).HasMaybeIntConversion();


public static PropertyBuilder<Maybe<int>> HasMaybeIntConversion(this PropertyBuilder<Maybe<int>> property)
        => property.HasConversion(
            x => x.Select(i => (int?)i).GetValueOrFallback(null),
            x=> x.HasValue 
                ? Maybe.From(x.Value) 
                : Maybe<int>.None);
```

The idea is to persist `null` for `Maybe.None` and to load `Maybe.None` from `null`.

However this doesn't work. When EF sees `null` in the database, it sets `null` to `MyProperty` (which is non nullable) without using the conversion rule.

To make it work I have to do the following changes:

```
#nullable enable
public class MyClass
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Maybe<int> MyProperty => MyPropertyNullable  ?? Maybe<int>.None;
    public Maybe<int>? MyPropertyNullable { get; set; }
}
#nullable restore
```

and in `MyContext`:

```
builderEntity.Property(o => o.MyPropertyNullable).HasMaybeIntConversion().HasColumnName(nameof(MyClass.MyProperty));
```

I find it quite heavy and ugly.

Would anyone know of a simpler way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Is there any benefit of using a Maybe<int> and all this additional EF configuration code over using int? with no need for any EF configuration code? The problem would go away with that approach, wouldn't it?

Comment: I still prefer Maybe<T> over T? as 'null' is not typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of EF Core. If the underlying database column is nullable, the mapped property must also be nullable.
If the value fetched from the database is `null`, EF skips the registered conversion method altogether.

The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13850).

> value converters do not generally allow the conversion of null to some other value. This is because the same value converter can be used for both nullable and non-nullable type.